# is there a way to know the knots used by spline()?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, splines

I use the function spline() to have a spline between x and y, as output I have a list of 2 elements (x e y), is there a way to know the knots used by spline()??

Comment: I’m not an expert on splines but in my understanding, aren’t the input points simply the knots? If not, you might be interested in `splinefunc` which, rather than returning the interpolated points, returns a *function* to perform the interpolation.

Comment: Hi @memy if the answer solves your problem please mark it "accepted" so other people can see it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

See the help page for `?spline`, it explains it quite well that the default default number of knots is three times the number of `x` points

> spline(x, y = NULL, n = 3*length(x), method = "fmm", xmin = min(x),
>   xmax = max(x), xout, ties = mean)
>
> "n"   if xout is left unspecified, interpolation takes place at n
>   equally spaced points spanning the interval [xmin, xmax].

Lets check it out:

```
sp <- spline(x=1:3, y=rnorm(3))
print(sp$x)
#### [1] 1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00 2.25 2.50 2.75 3.00
seq(from=1, to=3, length.out=3*3)
#### [1] 1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00 2.25 2.50 2.75 3.00
```

Comment: sorry , I was not clear,  but I want to have a coordinates of knots .

Comment: @memy i don't understand; the output of `spline`, the list you mention, is *by definition* the coordinates of the knots.. How doesn't this suits you? you don't want a list? You want the `y`coordinates of the original x points?

Comment: sorry, maybe I don't understand what is the knots.

Comment: I think the knots are the point where original x and interpolated values of x are the same

Comment: actually the way the default spline function works doesn't guarantee at all that output knots match with initial x points. If you want estimated `y` at your exact `x` locations, you should specify it in the `n` argument, for instance: `n=length(x)`

Comment: concerning the definition of a *knot*, well, to be fair the word doesn't even appear in the help page of `?spline`. It's probably more suitable in the context of smoothing splines